# Absolutely positioned div inside table not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a table that is centered.

I want to draw a line inside the table, but the line shows up on the left side of the table.

```css
table {
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: relative;
}
#winLine {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <div id="winLine"></div>
  <tr>
    <td id="0"></td>
    <td id="1"></td>
    <td id="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="3"></td>
    <td id="4"></td>
    <td id="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="6"></td>
    <td id="7"></td>
    <td id="8"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe putting a div inside a table is not valid HTML, and Chrome will move that div outside the table. If you just want a line, you could try using the :before pseudo class instead. https://jsfiddle.net/9yb657nj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<table>`, and use it as the context of positioning. Create a wrapper `<div>`, and use it to position the line:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative; 
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#winLine {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="winLine"></div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="0"></td>
      <td id="1"></td>
      <td id="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="3"></td>
      <td id="4"></td>
      <td id="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="6"></td>
      <td id="7"></td>
      <td id="8"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `div` element cannot be a child of a `table` element. It is invalid HTML.

In terms of allowable content of a `table` element, here's the relevant language from the spec:

> In this order: optionally a `caption` element, followed by zero or more
>   `colgroup` elements, followed optionally by a `thead` element, followed
>   optionally by a `tfoot` element, followed by either zero or more `tbody`
>   elements or one or more `tr` elements, followed optionally by a `tfoot`
>   element (but there can only be one `tfoot` element child in total),
>   optionally intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.
>
> *<sup>source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element</sup>*

So, no divs allowed. As a result, the browser forces the table element to start *after* the div.

Here's what's happening in Chrome (via dev tools):

[image]

The absolutely positioned div is now positioned relative to the initial containing block (`html` element), and is offset 50px from the left edge of the viewport.

Instead, consider a pseudo-element to make your line:

```css
table {
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
table::before {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="0"></td>
    <td id="1"></td>
    <td id="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="3"></td>
    <td id="4"></td>
    <td id="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="6"></td>
    <td id="7"></td>
    <td id="8"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```